Add stored procedure in EDMX file which is using TEMP table and PIVOT
I created this stored procedure in SQL Server:
SET FMTONLY OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE EmpTrainings
    @id = 0  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT q.Qualification, s.EmpName, qs.DateCompleted
    INTO #t1
    FROM QualStaff qs
    INNER JOIN Qual q ON qs.QualificationID = q.QualificationID
    INNER JOIN Staff s ON qs.StaffID = s.StaffID
    WHERE qs.StatusID = 1 AND qs.Id = @Id

    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(Qualification) 
                                            FROM #t1
                                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
                                         .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

    PRINT (@cols)

    DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) = ' SELECT * FROM #t1 PIVOT (MAX(DateCompleted) FOR Qualification IN ('+@cols+') ) pvt';

    EXECUTE(@query)

    DROP TABLE #t1

I am using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework v6.0. When I add this stored procedure to an .edmx file, it is not added at all.
Is there any way so I can add it or there is an alternative to call this stored procedure in this application?

Which database version are you targeting? All supported versions have STRING_AGG

I am using sql server 2019

Stored procedure is working well as per requirements but i cannot add in edmx.

How did you add the sproc to the EDMX? AFAICR (it has been a few years since I worked with EF-Framework model first: last time being converting a project with >100 tables to code first because EDMX + git goes badly) there is no sproc, UDF, ... create/drop support in EF Framework (you need to manage those things manually).

Remove the XML trick and use STRING_AGG then. Beyond that, what are you trying to do in the first place? You can't map an arbitrary number of columns to an object. For this code to work the columns must match the object properties

is working well as per requirements no it's not. It's using a trick that's not needed at all, it's slow, a lot harder to debug and can easily fail if any of the values contains eg < or >. Since you don't have an ORDER BY clause you lose its only benefit - retaining order.

@PanagiotisKanavos if i use STRING_AGG then i will be able to add in edmx file?

Why are you trying to do that in the first place? You CAN'T map arbitrary results to objects. EDMX isn't a database model, it's a file used to map relational constructs to application objects

Why pivot the data in the SQL layer? Why not handle the pivoting in the application layer, which is where you should be doing it.

@ThomA I am using PIVOT to convert the rows into columns as per client requirement to create report, how i can do in application layer, any hint please?

That explains nothing. EDMX is a mapping file, not a database definition or schema. You can't specify arbitrary stored procedures. You can specify stored procedures to load entities. It doesn't matter what the client requirements are, they can't change how the product works

Many reporting tools come with built-in features to pivot your data. SSRS, for example, has Matrices. I'm sure that whatever reporting tool you are using comes with something similar too. This, to me, all smells like an XY Problem. Return your data to your application in a normalised format, and then you can build the objects in your application around the statically defined result set you receive. Then you can have the application convert your rows into columns as you need.

@ThomA is there any solution so this stored procedure can be called without adding in edmx file in asp.net mvc app?

Why are you so committed to doing the dynamic pivoting in the SQL layer? Considering that the problem you are encountering is because you are dynamically pivoting in the SQL layer, that is likely a strong indicator that you have gone down the wrong path.

Why do you want to use an EDMX at all? Are you confusing it for a database driver? EDMX files were already obsolete when EF Classic 6 was released. You don't need them to map query results to objects. They were never needed to execute queries. SqlCommand executes queries

@ThomA i am not committed to do in sql layer, i can do in application layer. I am searching how to do it in asp.net. Thanks for the idea.

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes you are right, i am agree with this. I understand that now, that edmx cannot handle the stored procedures like this.

@Mushi it sounds like the real question is how to execute queries in general, not how to use EDMX. Queries are executed using the ADO.NET classes. To avoid the boilerplate code though many people use Dapper which generates automatically the SqlCommand, passes parameters to it and maps the results to objects.

@PanagiotisKanavos I know how to use ADO.Net, I don't want that people write code for me i was expecting a hint to handle this. Anyhow this is old application and owner don't allow to use ado.net. i will see other solutions. Thanks

You're already using ADO.NET. Entity Framework is a library that uses ADO.NET to map query results to objects and save object changes to the database. You can specify stored procedures for the load and save operations. You can't define the stored procedures with Entity Framework though

@PanagiotisKanavos  I will use this solution, what you suggest? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676020/using-an-entity-framework-connection-string-in-ado
